# Access request's URL parameters in stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

Can I access the request’s query params in stencil?
So if you go to http://example.com/?name=Bob
Can I render something like:

```
  Hello {{url.name}}!
```

It has to be server-side rendered, not browser JavaScript.

**Why?** Well, I actually want to share the results of a quiz on Facebook, so the `og:image` tag needs to point at a picture of the score. So I share a link like http://example.com/quiz/?quizScore=encodedscoreresult and the page then contains:

```html
<meta property="og:image" 
  content="https://myapi.example.com/quizresultsimage?quizScore=encodedscoreresult" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full solution, as you can't access an individual parameter's value, but...

The `settings.facebook_like_button.href` does contain the request URL, URL encoded as `https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fquiz%3FquizScore%3Dencodedscoreresult`

You can extract the *whole* query string from the URL using:

```
<meta property="og:image" 
  content="https://myapi.example.com/quizresultsimage{{get "search" (getObject "search" (urlParse (decodeURI settings.facebook_like_button.href)))}}" />
```

However, that will include all the query parameters, so that may be a security risk passing extra parameters from your stencil site to the api that aren't desired.

Simpler (and perhaps safer), you can pass the whole URL as a parameter in the meta tag, and then the API will have to decode it:

```
<meta property="og:image" 
  content="https://myapi.example.com/quizresultsimage?url={{settings.facebook_like_button.href}}" />
```

which results in:

```html
<meta property="og:image" 
  content="https://myapi.example.com/quizresultsimage?url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fquiz%3FquizScore%3Dencodedscoreresult" />
```

Because there is only one parameter in the query string, you can be sure you're not passing anything undesired to the target URL.

If you just need the decoded URL you can use:

```
{{assignVar "requestUrl" (decodeURI settings.facebook_like_button.href) }}
{{getVar "requestUrl"}}
```