# BigCommerce: stencil template - way to access query string from URL in template file?

Tags: templates, query-string, bigcommerce

New to BigCommerce, though have used templating in Magento / Shopify etc. extensively

Working with a Stencil based theme

Need a way of accessing the query string from the URL - most templating languages I've used before have this built in, but it seems with Big Commerce this is no so simple

(As background, we're running campaigns using different utm_ variables, and we want to conditionally display content based on which campaign they come in on)

Does anyone have any experience of having done this?

Comment: In JavaScript in the browser or in Stencil? If stencil, then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65968203/1402988

Comment: Sorry - should have clarified that.  Yes, in stencil specifically - I know I can grab / parse URL in JS but need to be able to pull through different stencil blocks to keep the page lightweight.  That solution looks like it may do the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular javascript to get the URL querystring params.

```js
// You can get the querystring from window.location
alert(`
The current URL is ${window.location}

The querystring is ${window.location.search || '(none)'}`);
```

There is a dedicated method to access the querystring:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams?hl=en

At this time, per the documentation, it is not supported by IEll:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#browser_compatibility

The solution for IE11 is to use a polyfill. Here is the recommended one:
https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params

Comment: Sorry, my fault for not being clear - looking for a way to do this using stencil itself, so that I can conditionally load different content blocks (more efficient than show/hide using JS for page load times) - appreciate the input though, thanks!